# What is the bulk compressibility of a system that contains both water and steam?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Let's say I have a volume that contains both water and steam, e.g. there is a lower pressure top part that is steam and a higher pressure bottom part that is water (temperature is constant).

If I know the fraction of steam and the respective compressibilities of both phases, how can I calculate the bulk compressibility of the whole system?

Comment: @tpg2114 if the pressure difference is purely due to hydrostatic pressure (gravity), wouldn't the system be at equilibrium?

Comment: The pressure doesn't change as you compress it or expand it isothermally, so the bulk compressibility of the combination of liquid and vapor is infinite.

Comment: @ChesterMiller what will change if I allow the temperature to vary during compression/expansion?

Comment: The bulk compressibility is based on constant temperature.

Comment: unless we say it's isentropic?

Comment: Is that the behavior you want to look at?  If so, are you willing to initially focus exclusively on cases where the temperature and pressure are much lower than the critical values so that we can assume the density of the liquid is nearly constant and the vapor behaves like an ideal gas, or is it important to you to also include cases where the pressure is high enough for gas-phase non-idealities to be involved?

Comment: @ChesterMiller ideal gas and constant liquid density would do just fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isentropic Case:

Let $T=T_R$ and $P=P_R$ be the reference state of zero enthalpy for liquid water.  So $H(T_R, P_R)=0$.  Let $n_L$ be the number of moles of liquid water in the cylinder and $n_V$ be the number of moles of water vapor.  Then, the enthalpy of the liquid phase in the cylinder is:
$$H_L=n_L[C_{PL}(T-T_R)+V_L(P-P_R)]$$and the enthalpy of the vapor phase in the cylinder is:$$H_V=n_V [C_{PL}(T-T_R)+V_L(P-P_R)+\lambda(T)]$$where $\lambda(T)$ is the heat of vaporization at temperature T and pressure P, and $C_{PL} $ is the molar heat capacity of the liquid, and $V_L$ is the molar volume of the liquid.  So the total enthalpy of the cylinder contents is $$H=n[C_{PL}(T-T_R)+V_L(P-P_R)]+n_V\lambda(T)\tag{1}$$where $$n=n_V+n_L=const\tag{2}$$
The total volume of vapor and liquid in the cylinder is $$V=n_LV_L+n_VRT/P\tag{3}$$

The variations in temperature and pressure are going to be related by the Clapeyron equation:
$$\frac{dP}{dT}=\frac{\lambda(T)}{T[\frac{RT}{P}-V_L]}\tag{4}$$
Now the next thing we will do is increase the pressure P slightly by dP.  This causes a change in the temperature dT, a change in the number of moles of liquid $dn_L$, a change in the number of moles of vapor $-dn_L$, a change in total volume dV, and a change in total enthalpy dH.  For an isentropic pressure change dP, the behavior is constrained by the first law which requires that $$dH=VdP\tag{5}$$

I think I'll stop here for now an let you ask any questions you might have.  I'll also let you continue the development if you'd like.

Comment: thanks for the answer! That cleared things up a bit. Like that it is important to not ignore the relation between temperature change and pressure change